# No module named 'sklearn' in LabVIEW

Tags: python, scikit-learn, labview

I'm trying to run a python code that has an intelligent algorithm in LabVIEW using a python node, and I got the following error: Python returned the following error: <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'> No module named 'sklearn'. I tried with simpler code (without sklearn) and the code ran as expected. I've installed scikit-learn using pip, and if I try to run the python script from the command line, it works. But for the same python script, LabVIEW doesn't find the sklearn library. Do you know what I can do, or if there are some settings that maybe I configured wrongly?

Comment: What version of LabVIEW are you using? It might be that you are using 32-bit LabVIEW but have installed the scikit-learn library for 64-bit python

Comment: See https://www.ni.com/en-gb/support/documentation/supplemental/18/installing-python-for-calling-python-code.html and check out the "before you begin" section

Comment: Are you sure that LabVIEW is seeing the same Python installation where you installed scikit-learn? As @John's link suggests, check that your system path contains the directory where this Python is installed.